# What does this Cisco Router firewall configuration mean?

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco, router

I have a Cisco 881w that I have attempted to set up a very basic firewall on, but I am not convinced I have done this correctly. Below is the configuration pertaining to the firewall and access lists (some of which I set up, some of which is factory defaults). I am hoping someone with more experience of this can tell me exactly what I have set up, so I can use that as a basis to improve my basic first attempt and set it up properly (I followed a guide to get this far and don't really know what I'm doing yet).

```
!
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 ftp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 h323
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 icmp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 netshow
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 rcmd
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 realaudio
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 rtsp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 esmtp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 sqlnet
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 streamworks
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 tftp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 tcp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 udp
ip inspect name DEFAULT100 vdolive
ip inspect name firewall-out tcp
ip inspect name firewall-out udp
ip inspect name firewall-out ica
ip inspect name firewall-out icabrowser
ip inspect name firewall-out ftp
ip inspect name firewall-out smtp
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
access-list 1 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.7
access-list 23 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.7
access-list 100 deny   ip host 255.255.255.255 any
access-list 100 deny   ip 127.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 100 permit ip any any
access-list 100 deny   tcp any any
access-list 100 deny   udp any any
access-list 100 deny   ip any any
access-list 100 deny   icmp any any
access-list 101 permit udp any eq bootps any eq bootpc
access-list 101 deny   ip 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 101 permit icmp any any echo-reply
access-list 101 permit icmp any any time-exceeded
access-list 101 permit icmp any any unreachable
access-list 101 deny   ip 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 101 deny   ip 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255 any
access-list 101 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
access-list 101 deny   ip 127.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 101 deny   ip host 255.255.255.255 any
access-list 101 deny   ip any any
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 102 permit ip 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 199 permit ip any any
!
```

The 'firewall-out' stuff was me, as were bits of the access-list. I know what I was aiming to do (basic firewall to protect us from anything originating outside the network), but what I would like to know is what exactly have I set up here?
Also, any information on how I can test what the firewall I think I have set up is letting in and out would be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what do you want clarification on ? An understand of the access lists you've applied, the protocols you've asked it to inspect or the fact that you've allowed CEF over IPv4 but not IPv6?

Comment: I want to understand the access lists I've applied.
I also want to know if I've done anything silly with the protocols I've asked it to inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**access-list 1**

> access-list 1 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.7

This allows network range 10.10.10.1-6

---

**access-list 23**

> access-list 23 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.7

This is the same as access-list 1

---

**access-list 100**

> access-list 100 deny   ip host 255.255.255.255 any
>
> access-list 100 deny   ip 127.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
>
> access-list 100 permit ip any any

This explicitly blocks access to anyone pretending to be the global network mask of 255.255.255.255 or any address claiming to be from local host range before allowing any IP through.

> access-list 100 deny   tcp any any
>
> access-list 100 deny   udp any any
>
> access-list 100 deny   ip any any
>
> access-list 100 deny   icmp any any

This seems pointless in my view because you've already allowed any IP through. If you want to block any of these they need to go before the any IP permit.

---

**access-list 101**

> access-list 101 permit udp any eq bootps any eq bootpc

All UPD for DHCP via BOOTP protocol

> access-list 101 deny   ip 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255 any

Block anyone from the 10.10.10.0-255 range

> access-list 101 permit icmp any any echo-reply
>
> access-list 101 permit icmp any any time-exceeded
>
> access-list 101 permit icmp any any unreachable

Allow any echo-reply, time-exceeded or unreachable packet

> access-list 101 deny   ip 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
>
> access-list 101 deny   ip 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255 any
>
> access-list 101 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
>
> access-list 101 deny   ip 127.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
>
> access-list 101 deny   ip host 255.255.255.255 any
>
> access-list 101 deny   ip any any

A whole bunch of denying IPs though most are pointless given the last line blocks everyone.

> access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any

This seems to be pointless as well given the earlier deny. You would need to move this above the deny line to be effective.

---

**access-list 102**

> access-list 102 permit ip 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255 any

Allow 172.16.0.0-255

---

**access-list 199**

> access-list 199 permit ip any any

All any IP

**EDIT**:
As noted here: http://www.cs.odu.edu/~csi/cisco/router_configuration/access_list.html

> **Note:** the end of the access list contains an implicit deny statement for everything if it did not find a match before reaching the end. Further, with standard access lists, if you omit the mask from an associated IP host address access list specification, 0.0.0.0 is assumed to be the mask.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks pretty comprehensive, will have to work through it tomorrow and tidy up the redundant statements and confirm it is all what I was going for (looks close but not exactly terse).